# Adding byte[] values to List with AddRange

Tags: c#

I cannot seem to add a `byte[]` to a `List<byte[]>` using `AddRange`

```
List<byte[]> dataStream = new List<byte[]>();
byte[] dataIdentifed = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)this.dataIdentifier);
dataStream.AddRange(dataIdentifed);
```

> Cannot convert `byte[]` to `IEnumerable<byte[]>`

Comment: You have no range, use just `Add`

Comment: It seems you should have a List<byte> instead of List<byte[]>. byte[] is IEnumerable<byte> while List<byte[]>.AddRange expects IEnumerable<byte[]>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your intention is adding a series of bytes into a List :

```
List<byte> dataStream = new List<byte>();
byte[] dataIdentifed = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)this.dataIdentifier);
dataStream.AddRange(dataIdentifed);
```

Comment: Where is the facepalm buton.